# Чтение датаграммы по частям

Tags: c++, qt, сетевое-программирование

Можно ли как то прочитать датаграмму из сокета по частям? Работаю с qudpsocket. Грубо говоря мне нужно пустить сокет через цепочку обработчиков, каждый из которых вычитает из начала сокета свое количество байт. 
Примерно так: обработчик i вычитывает с 1 байта n байт и они удаляются. i+1 обработчик вычитывает с 1 байта (теперь байт n+1 стал первым на считывание в буфере) до m и так далее

Все возможности по считыванию из сокета которые я нашёл, это либо все либо ничего.

Comment: my_socket.read(<Bytes needed>); https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#read-1

Comment: одну датаграмму из сокета по частям разумными средствами читать нельзя... если хочешь, то можешь просто обернуть полученные данные в `QBuffer` и читать из него...

Comment: Кроме как перекинуть весь пакет в pipe (или tcp) ничего в голову не лезет (*шутка* -)). Можно попробовать (если задача позволяет) использовать [*recvmsg*](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvmsg) с iovec, разбрасывающим данные по нескольким буферам. Если определить размер буферов и их смещение можно только по некоторому "заголовку", то можно прочесть только его, оставив пакет в системе (флаг `MSG_PEEK`) для последующего recvmsg.

Comment: Вы же получаете датаграмму целиком, а не по частям. Полученный от сокета массив можно обрабатывать с помощью QBuffer и QDataStream.